# Center Text in JQuery Mobile Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Here's what I have:
[image: Screenshot]

Here's a JSFiddle with my code in it: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skbeez/pyvm8678/)

I want to center the text in the checkboxes and I've all of the following to no avail...

I've tried each of these separately and they have absolutely no effect on centering the text

```
.ui-btn-text {
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.custom {
text-align: center;
}
```

What am I missing? I've tried searching google everywhere but all the examples I've found don't seem work in my case. Any help would be appreciated.

I also want to center all the rows of buttons as well.

Comment: Try: "text-align:center !important;". Does that work? Also make sure if you are using .custom, the checkboxes actually have the custom class!

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-align` for `label`:

```
label {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pyvm8678/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem with css:

```
label.ui-btn.ui-corner-all.ui-btn-inherit.ui-checkbox-off {
  text-align: center;
}
label.ui-btn.ui-corner-all.ui-btn-inherit.ui-checkbox-on {
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pyvm8678/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
.pull-center {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-checkbox label.ui-btn{
    text-align: center;
 }
```